# Perl regex with a negative lookahead behaves unexpectedly

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm attempting to match /ezmlm-(any word except 'weed' or 'return')\s+/ with a regex. The following demonstrates a foreach loop which does the right thing, and an attempted regex which almost does:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tests = (
    {  msg => "want 'yes', string has ezmlm, but not weed or return",
       str => q[|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-reject '<snip>'],
    },
    {  msg => "want 'yes', array  has ezmlm, but not weed or return",
       str => [ <DATA> ],
    },
    {  msg => "want 'no' , has ezmlm-weed",
       str => q[|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-weed '<snip>'],
    },
    {  msg => "want 'no' , doesn't have ezmlm-anything",
       str => q[|/usr/local/bin/else '<snip>'],
    },
    {  msg => "want 'no' , ezmlm email pattern",
       str => q[crazy/but/legal/ezmlm-wacky@example.org],
    },
);

print "foreach regex\n";
foreach ( @tests ) {
    print doit_fe( ref $_->{str} ? @{$_->{str}} : $_->{str} ) ? "yes" : "no";
    print "\t";
    print doit_re( ref $_->{str} ? @{$_->{str}} : $_->{str} ) ? "yes" : "no";
    print "\t<--- $_->{msg}\n";
};

# for both of the following subs:
#   @_ will contain one or more lines of data
#   match the pattern /ezmlm-(any word except 'weed' or 'return')\s+/

sub doit_fe {
    my $has_ezmlm = 0;
    foreach ( @_ ) {
        next if $_ !~ m/ezmlm-(.*?)\s/;
        return 0 if $1 eq 'weed' or $1 eq 'return';
        $has_ezmlm++;
    };
    return $has_ezmlm;
};

sub doit_re { return grep /ezmlm-(?!weed|return)/, @_; };

__DATA__
|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-reject '<snip>'
|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-issubn '<snip>'
|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-send '<snip>'
|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-archive '<snip>'
|/usr/local/bin/ezmlm-warn '<snip>'
```

The output of the sample program is as follows:

```
foreach regex
yes yes <--- want 'yes', string has ezmlm, but not weed or return
yes yes <--- want 'yes', array  has ezmlm, but not weed or return
no  no  <--- want 'no' , has ezmlm-weed
no  no  <--- want 'no' , doesn't have ezmlm-anything
no  yes <--- want 'no' , ezmlm email pattern
```

In the last instance, the regex fails, matching a goofy but legal email address. If I amend the regex placing a \s after the negative lookahead pattern like so:

```
grep /ezmlm-(?!weed|return)\s+/
```

The regex fails to match at all. I'm supposing it has to do with the how the negative pattern works. I've tried making the negation non-greedy, but it seems there's some lesson buried in 'perldoc perlre' that is escaping me. Is it possible to do this with a single regex?

Comment: This is odd. Try:  `/ezmlm-(?!(weed|return))/`.  I'm not sure it'll change anything, but it's worth asking...

Comment: The e-mail matches the regex on here: http://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

Answer (score 4):

The negative look-ahead is *zero-width* which means that the regex

```
/ezmlm-(?!weed|return)\s+/
```

will only match if one or more space characters immediately follow `"ezmlm-"`.

The pattern

```
/ezmlm-(?!weed|return)/
```

will match

```
"crazy/but/legal/ezmlm-wacky@example.org"
```

because it contains `"ezmlm-"` not followed by `"weedy"` or `"return"`.

Try

```
/ezmlm-(?!weed|return)\S+\s+/
```

where `\S+` is one or more non-space characters (or instead use `[^@\s]+` if you want to deny email addresses even if followed by a space).

Comment: So *that's* what zero width means. Thanks Mike!